# Break a subtitle before hyphen

Tags: bash

I have a subtitle file. I want break all subtitles with hyphens. After I just want two-line subtitles. For example:

From:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,000
- hi. - hi.

2
00:00:01,100 --> 00:00:02,000
- How are you? - I'm fine.
I work a lot.
```

To:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,000
- hi.
- hi.

2
00:00:01,100 --> 00:00:02,000
- How are you?
- I'm fine. I work a lot.
```

I tried:

```
cat source.srt | sed 's/ - /\n\0/g' > target.srt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gnu sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/ - /\n- /' file
```

Comment: This code works: cat source.srt | sed 's/ - /\n- /g' > target.txt. But "I work a lot" is in the third line. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The thing is that `I work a lot.` is already on a separate line. To remove that new line and bring it to previous line will be error prone unless you clarify using what logic should we do this.

Comment: The first person speaks: "How are you?". The second person speaks: "I'm fine. I work a lot.". I want to bring the spoken words of a person on a single line. Each hyphen represents a person. This is my problem.

Comment: Actually it would be better be if you create a new question with this new requirement to get more answers. I will also try to work on it from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all " - " with "- \n"
However that will put "I work a lot." into a third line.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed command is wrong. Try:

```
sed -i "s/ - /\n- /g" filename.srt
```

In your example, you make another edit, which you did not state in your question. This command does just what you asked.